# ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

How to call an existing Login stored procedure using `UserManager` or `SignInManager`? Is it possible I have my existing DB structure and I want to create authorization and authentication from stored procedure.

But when I am using according to my requirement I get errors:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ISqlApplicationUserRepository sqlApplicationUserRepository;

    public AuthenticateController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration, ISqlApplicationUserRepository sqlApplicationUserRepository)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
        this.sqlApplicationUserRepository = sqlApplicationUserRepository;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(SiteUser model)
    {
    //this function i want to use instead of .FindByNameAsync

        var user1 = sqlApplicationUserRepository.GetUserProfile(model.UserName);//this function i want to use instead of .FindByNameAsync

        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

    //so what change i need to do in this section ir in signinmanager to authenticate my user from membership tables using store procedure. 
        if (user1 != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user1, model.Password))
        {
            var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user1);

            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user1.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }

            var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to execute a stored procedure to get user info from your database that stores records of ASP.Net Core Identity, you can try to inject an instance of `ApplicationDbContext`, then [perform ADO.NET operation](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#leveraging-ado.net-via-the-context.database-property) to execute your stored procedure

Comment: You should edit the question and include the tag of language the code is written in.